# WiFi can't connect 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT and DEAUTH_LEAVING

Tags: wireless, 16.04, atheros

Ubuntu 16.04 on UEFI Chipset **Atheros AR9485**, on windows 10 is the same not work

```
lshw -c network
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:8d:5c:e3:88:75
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe900fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 60:e3:27:24:e5:0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:fe800000-fe87ffff memory:fe880000-fe88ffff

sudo dmesg | grep ath
[   12.636516] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.643638] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x21
[   12.643639] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   12.643641] ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU
[   12.643642] ath: Regpair used: 0x21
[   12.891402] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

sudo dmesg | grep wlp
[   12.891402] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   29.768305] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   29.782362] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   30.441829] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  426.495662] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  426.515481] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  427.521531] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  427.562125] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  428.866011] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 2/3)
[  429.565278] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  429.565376] wlp3s0: associated
[  429.565399] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[  430.612823] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  437.640774] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[  438.542598] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  438.562646] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  439.568431] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  439.605263] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  440.865148] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 2/3)
[  441.608249] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  441.608331] wlp3s0: associated
[  442.612472] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  449.639611] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[  450.557775] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  450.577663] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  451.583377] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  451.620234] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  452.864288] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 2/3)
[  453.623324] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  453.623405] wlp3s0: associated
[  454.627567] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  461.654641] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[  462.564626] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  462.584507] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  463.590518] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  463.623296] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  464.851173] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 2/3)
[  465.626273] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  465.626357] wlp3s0: associated
[  466.634404] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  473.661779] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[  474.543485] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab
[  474.563594] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  475.569526] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  475.610243] wlp3s0: associate with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab (try 1/3)
[  476.087644] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  476.090328] wlp3s0: aborting association with c4:27:95:bf:0b:ab by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

With nohwcrypt I receive that result :

```
[   13.442577] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   31.301987] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   31.316009] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   32.325719] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  218.161456] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  218.187056] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  218.202225] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  218.296818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  229.199892] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  229.220029] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  229.862815] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  230.225963] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  230.266560] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  230.874514] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  231.898434] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 3/3)
[  232.269817] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  232.269900] wlp3s0: associated
[  232.269917] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[  232.270992] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (Reason: 9=STA_REQ_ASSOC_WITHOUT_AUTH)
[  239.579091] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  239.599255] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  240.604974] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  240.637767] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  241.897723] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  242.640678] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=12 aid=1)
[  242.640686] wlp3s0: 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 denied association (code=12)
[  243.906642] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  243.926702] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  244.861338] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  244.932434] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  244.969436] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  245.873131] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  246.861317] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 3/3)
[  246.972470] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  246.972551] wlp3s0: associated
[  246.973463] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (Reason: 9=STA_REQ_ASSOC_WITHOUT_AUTH)
[  264.792703] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  264.812955] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  265.818621] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  265.855352] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  266.871419] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  267.858468] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=12 aid=1)
[  267.858475] wlp3s0: 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 denied association (code=12)
[  279.375190] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  279.395518] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  280.401119] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  280.441997] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  281.893745] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  282.445123] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=12 aid=1)
[  282.445130] wlp3s0: 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 denied association (code=12)
[  293.647970] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  677.645980] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  677.666177] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  678.671957] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  678.704692] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  679.832583] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  680.707752] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  680.707841] wlp3s0: associated
[  680.707855] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[  690.976770] wlp3s0: authenticate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26
[  690.996890] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  691.819670] wlp3s0: send auth to 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  692.002743] wlp3s0: authenticated
[  692.035481] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 1/3)
[  692.819573] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 2/3)
[  693.831440] wlp3s0: associate with 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (try 3/3)
[  694.038496] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  694.038579] wlp3s0: associated
[  694.038705] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 0c:41:3e:f0:3b:26 (Reason: 9=STA_REQ_ASSOC_WITHOUT_AUTH)
```

Some one has any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 5):

The messgae, "Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT" suggests that there is a problem with the password. I assume that you have double- and triple-checked that the password you have entered is correct in both Ubuntu and Windows. Please check in the router's administration pages to verify it again.

Next, there are two methods to achieve encryption, hardware and software. Try disabling hardware encryption and see if it helps. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Now can you connect? If so, we'll make the change permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

If you are still unable to connect, then check again the encryption key in the router. Use only numbers and letters and do not use symbols or spaces. Reboot the router.

Next, we see:

> ath: Country alpha2 being used: AU

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: Still not work but behavior has changed , after providing password it asks again after few seconds. New code I have attached to question thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had an 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT because the station tried to use WPA3 but the access point (hotspot with NetworkManager) only supported WPA2. Modifying the station/client config to use WPA2 worked around that problem.