# Cannot connect to Wifi — 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT

Tags: 16.04, wireless, connection

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I aim to connect to a Wifi network which uses the WPA AES/TKIP encryption protocol. I've double and triple-checked the password; the connection works on macOS, on my iPhone, but not on Ubuntu.

It is likely the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843912/wifi-cant-connect-4way-handshake-timeout-and-deauth-leaving), but the help which was provided unfortunately didn't solve my problem.

`sudo lspci -s 01:00.0 -vv` output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Option N.V. Option GTM67x PCIe WiFi Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [60] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-15-17-ff-ff-24-14-12
    Capabilities: [170 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

`dmesg | tail -n 29` output:

```
[ 4681.522874] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 4681.524081] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 4693.558908] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 5470.321252] wlp1s0: authenticate with b2:...:78
[ 5470.334748] wlp1s0: send auth to b2:...:78 (try 1/3)
[ 5470.338779] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 5470.343477] wlp1s0: associate with b2:...:78 (try 1/3)
[ 5470.352418] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from b2:...:78 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[ 5470.352576] wlp1s0: associated
[ 5476.597713] wlp1s0: deauthenticated from b2:...:78 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[ 5488.915548] wlp1s0: authenticate with b2:...:78
[ 5488.930278] wlp1s0: send auth to b2:...:78 (try 1/3)
[ 5488.931998] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 5488.934364] wlp1s0: associate with b2:...:78 (try 1/3)
[ 5488.943316] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from b2:...:78 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[ 5488.943476] wlp1s0: associated
[ 5494.695405] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from b2:...:78 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 5499.363802] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

`nmcli device wifi list` output:

```
*  SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
   FreeWifi              Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  62      ***               
   FreeWifi_secure       Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  62      ***   WPA1 802.1X 
   Kougelhopf            Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  62      ***   WPA1        
   porchif               Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  37      **    WPA1        
   NUMERICABLE-xxxx      Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  35      **    WPA1 WPA2   
   orange                Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  30      *                 
   DIRECT-xxxxxx Series  Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  29      *     WPA2        
   FreeWifi_secure       Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  29      *     WPA2 802.1X 
   XXXX-xxxx             Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  27      *     WPA1 WPA2   
   FreeWifi_secure       Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  27      *     WPA2 802.1X 
   Bbox-xxxxxxxx         Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  25      *     WPA1 WPA2   
   FreeWifi              Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  25      *                 
   Livebox-xxxx          Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  22      *     WPA1 WPA2
```

(I want to connect to the `Kougelhopf` router.)

`nmcli -f GENERAL,WIFI-PROPERTIES dev show wlp1s0` output:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (Option GTM67x PCIe WiFi Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath9k
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-58-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:0C:E3:6F:60:EE
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
```

`sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | sort` output:

```
58 unit files listed.
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service          enabled
NetworkManager-wait-online.service         enabled
NetworkManager.service                     enabled
UNIT FILE                                  STATE  
accounts-daemon.service                    enabled
acpid.path                                 enabled
acpid.socket                               enabled
anacron-resume.service                     enabled
anacron.service                            enabled
apport-forward.socket                      enabled
apt-daily-upgrade.timer                    enabled
apt-daily.timer                            enabled
autovt@.service                            enabled
avahi-daemon.service                       enabled
avahi-daemon.socket                        enabled
bluetooth.service                          enabled
brltty.service                             enabled
cron.service                               enabled
cups-browsed.service                       enabled
cups.path                                  enabled
cups.service                               enabled
cups.socket                                enabled
dbus-org.bluez.service                     enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service         enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.thermald.service      enabled
display-manager.service                    enabled
dns-clean.service                          enabled
getty@.service                             enabled
gpu-manager.service                        enabled
lightdm.service                            enabled
network-manager.service                    enabled
networking.service                         enabled
pppd-dns.service                           enabled
remote-fs.target                           enabled
resolvconf.service                         enabled
rsyslog.service                            enabled
snap-core-7396.mount                       enabled
snap-core18-1074.mount                     enabled
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-90.mount     enabled
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount    enabled
snap-mailspring-374.mount                  enabled
snap-vlc-1049.mount                        enabled
snap-zenity-18.mount                       enabled
snapd.autoimport.service                   enabled
snapd.core-fixup.service                   enabled
snapd.seeded.service                       enabled
snapd.service                              enabled
snapd.snap-repair.timer                    enabled
snapd.socket                               enabled
snapd.system-shutdown.service              enabled
syslog.service                             enabled
systemd-timesyncd.service                  enabled
thermald.service                           enabled
ufw.service                                enabled
unattended-upgrades.service                enabled
ureadahead.service                         enabled
uuidd.socket                               enabled
whoopsie.service                           enabled
```

And `iwconfig wlp1s0` output:

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=13 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` TKIP is quite insecure; I don't recommend it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you also add the output of ` nmcli -f GENERAL,WIFI-PROPERTIES dev show wlp1s0` as well as `sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | sort` . There might a service conflict.
`

Comment: oh, and can you also post `iwconfig  wlp1s0` and change the original `lspci` command to `sudo lspci -s 01:00.0 -vv`